Show Popup Dialog When Receiving Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification in Background
I'm currently developing an application that needs to handle tasks in the background, even when the app is closed. Specifically, my scenario is as follows:
When the app receives a notification from the server via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)—whether the app is running in the background or is completely closed—a popup dialog should appear on top of all other apps. I intend to achieve this by starting an activity that displays the dialog.
I have attempted to implement a BroadcastReceiver, but I encountered an issue: the OnReceive event is triggered only when the app is in the foreground (on top).
How can I ensure that the popup dialog is shown when a notification is received, even if the app is not in the foreground or is closed? Is there a specific way to handle this scenario in .NET MAUI?
[Activity(Theme = "@style/OverlayTheme", ExcludeFromRecents = true, Label = "ColorOverlayActivity", NoHistory = true)]
public class ColorOverlayActivity : Activity
{
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            // Retrieve the message from the intent
            var message = Intent.GetStringExtra("message");
    
            // Display the message in an alert dialog
        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.SetMessage(message);
            dialog.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
            {
                Finish();
            });
    
            dialog.Show();
        }
    }

And the BroadcastReceiver :
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
public class PopupReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var popupIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ColorOverlayActivity));
        popupIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartActivity(popupIntent);
    }
}

The PopupReceiver is registered in MainActivity, and as I mentioned, the OnReceive method is triggered only when the app is in the foreground.
Thanks.

What's the version of the nuget you used in your app? Have you tried to update it to the latest version?

Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.5" and "Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.6"

You can try to update the nugets to the latest version.
